# How to create, build, run and debug a Rust program with the Atom editor?

Tags: windows, rust, atom-editor

I am looking for step-by-step instructions to create, build, run and debug a first Rust application inside the Atom editor.

So far I have installed the Atom editor, installed the package `language-rust`, and fruitlessly tried to find an option inside the editor to create a Rust "project" or "package", and my google-fu failed miserably.

Disclaimer: I am on Windows, very familiar with Visual Studio and not familiar with *nix-like development environments, but eager to try Rust.

Comment: You might also be interested in [RustDT, an eclipse-based rust IDE](http://rustdt.github.io/)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Install the [`build`](https://atom.io/packages/build) package.
2. Install the [`build-cargo`](https://atom.io/packages/build-cargo) package
3. Press <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
4. Enter `cmd` and press <kbd>Return</kbd> or click `Ok`
5. type `cd C:\path\of\your\projects\folder` (if it's on another drive, type `d:` and press <kbd>Return</kbd> before using the `cd` command)
6. type `cargo new --bin your_project_name` (there must not be a folder with the same name)
7. close the command prompt
8. go to the new folder in the Windows Explorer
9. right-click the folder and select `Open with Atom`
10. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> and select "run" from the dropdown list
11. If you prefer Atom to automatically jump to the first error it encounters, you can change this setting in the `build` package's settings by activating the checkbox for "Automatically scroll on build error"
12. If you want inline popups for errors and warnings, install the [`linter`](https://atom.io/packages/linter) package.

If someone figures out debugging with Atom, that would be a tremendous help.

Comment: I always get an error `Unable to execute with sh: cargo.
Make sure 'cmd' and 'cwd' exists and have correct access permissions.`, even when I run it as administrator

Comment: I'm very sorry, but my post was outdated, I updated it to reflect the improved cargo support. Make sure to delete your `.atom-build.json` and restart Atom.

Comment: I tried it before (even befor adding .atom-build.json, so particularly this is why i added it, because simple way `plug-and-play` didn't work to me), but I always get `No tool can provide any build configurations.` on step 10

Comment: I've got it, `build-cargo` plugin should be also installed

Comment: There is a way to debug using visual studio code with pretty printers. Maybe something alike may be done in Atom? https://medium.com/@royalstream/rust-development-using-vs-code-on-os-x-debugging-included-bc10c9863777#.ervrbub5x

Comment: @MajesticRa the problem is that noone has written a gdb interface for atom yet ;)

Comment: Ahh... Sorry. I'm not very familiar with Atom ecosystem, but heard it is used for debugging too and therefore was sure a gdb interface exists.